Can anyone tell me what this notification is?
What is this icon?

This is not my phone, so I cannot click on the app. Any info would be appreciated.

Unfortunately, with million of Android apps exist, and even some of them are distributed off-site/private, it's infeasible for the community to identify random notification icon anymore. Sorry.
